# How can I change text color of items from a picker dialog in android?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-styles

I'm trying to change the text color of the picker dialog using styles.xml, I'm able to change title and button colors but nothing changes the items color. My desire is my background in white and text in black but due to this issue, I had to change background color to see the items. This is how my styles.xml looks like:

```
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#5cc7a3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#5cc7a3</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>

 <style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
   <!--buttons-->
  <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
   <!--title-->
   <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
   <!--text-->
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
   <!--selection list-->
   <item name="android:textColorTertiary">#000000</item>
   <!--background-->
   <item name="android:background">#5cc7a3</item>
 </style>
```

[image: this is how the dialog appears]

This is how the dialog appears right now, if background is white, I can't see items:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve that by using a custom renderer that I've found on google. For those who are searching for a solution here goes the code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Widget;
using BindablePicker;
using BindablePicker.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Color = Android.Graphics.Color;
using Orientation = Android.Widget.Orientation;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PickerRenderer), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace BindablePicker.Droid
{
 public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer//, ViewRenderer<Picker, EditText>
 {

     IElementController ElementController => Element;

     public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
     {
         AutoPackage = false;

     }


     private AlertDialog _dialog;


     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
     {
         base.OnElementChanged(e);
         Control.Click += Control_Click;
     }


     protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
     {
         if (disposing)
         {
             Control.Click -= Control_Click;
             //var picker = (Picker)Element;
             //picker.PropertyChanged -= Control_Click;
         }


         base.Dispose(disposing);
     }

     private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Picker model = Element;
         model.Title = "changed";

         var picker = new NumberPicker(Context);

         if (model.Items != null && model.Items.Any())
         {
             // set style here

             picker.MaxValue = model.Items.Count - 1;
             picker.MinValue = 0;

             picker.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
             picker.ForegroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.Black);
             picker.SetDisplayedValues(model.Items.ToArray());
             picker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
             picker.Value = model.SelectedIndex;

         }


         var layout = new LinearLayout(Context) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
         layout.AddView(picker);
         layout.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);

         var titleView = new TextView(Context);

         titleView.Text = "hmmmm";
         titleView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ForestGreen);

         ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, true);

         var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
         builder.SetView(layout);

         builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");

         //builder.SetCustomTitle(titleView);
         builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancelar  ", (s, a) =>
         {
             ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
             // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
             // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
             Control?.ClearFocus();
             _dialog = null;
         });
         builder.SetPositiveButton("Confirmar ", (s, a) =>
         {
             ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, picker.Value);
             // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed on SelectedIndexChanged.
             // In this case, the Element & Control will no longer exist.
             if (Element != null)
             {
                 if (model.Items.Count > 0 && Element.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                     Control.Text = model.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];
                 ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                 // It is also possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                 // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                 Control?.ClearFocus();
             }
             _dialog = null;
         });

         Control.Text = "Control";

         _dialog = builder.Create();
         _dialog.DismissEvent += (ssender, args) =>
         {
             ElementController?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
         };
         _dialog.Show();
     }

    }
 }
```

Comment: ,Glad to hear that you have sloved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line in your theme :

```
 <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/Black</item> // change color according to your requirement
```

Comment: I already have added this as you can see at  <style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" ... And now I added to others themes also but It doesn't work, unfortunately.